# Unable to retrieve complete serial data

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino, serial-port, port

Im developing a personal project to read RFID Tags from Arduino.
When I read the 1st tag; I receive the total bytes and information is processed correctly.
However when reading the following times; seems like that my PC is "seeing" a received event for the first byte (of 8) received; and then processing the data received at a time; (when there are only 6 bytes in the buffer).
After sending those 6 bytes to be processed, it notices a new byte incomming and processes that, and the bytes following; creating results in two messages of 6 and 2 bytes.

Result Example:

> 1st Read: Message: 06DB0934
>
> 2nd Read: Message 1: 06
>
> 2nd Read: Message 1: DB0934

Bellow my modest code:

```
private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (port.IsOpen)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        idTag = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);

        // Custom Event that will update Information on Main Form
        OnTagReceived(); 
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get round this issue?

Comment: Looks like you need to put the Read in a loop of sorts, so that you can continue reading until you have received all the data you need.

Comment: Hello @NibblyPig: I've tried using StringBuilder and Append each Char from Serial.Read; and in a different attempt: 2 foreach loops; one to get the chars from incomming data other to create a string. But no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is in data received, you need to store the incoming bytes in a buffer until you have read enough.

Keep your buffer separate as a global/instance variable,

`private string _tagBuffer;`

Then in your method

```
if (port.IsOpen)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = port.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    _tagBuffer += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);

    if (_tagBuffer.Length >= 8)
    {        
        idTag = tagBuffer.substring(0, 8);
        tagBuffer = tagBuffer.substring(8); // might be 9

        OnTagReceived();
    }
}
```

Might be nicer to put the tag in the arguments sent to the event instead of putting them in `idTag`.

Comment: Superb! Worked perfectly Thank you so much.So that's how you count the bytes!
It works with 8 chars. But I understood that a Space or Line could cause increment of this value.
What I did not understand was why the "StartIndex" of tagBuffer = tagBuffer.Substring(8); is also 8. I mean; starting at the end?

Comment: Because it's 0 indexed, so 0, 8 means read 8 characters starting at position 0 (which is the 1st character). Substring(8) means start at position 8 (which is the 9th character) and read the rest of the string. So basically it cuts out the first 8 characters since we've already dealt with them. I put // might be 9 because I wasn't sure if that overload was zero indexed and was too lazy to look it up